# How to make a transparent button/animation without a button (flet)

Tags: python, python-3.x, web, flet

I have a website, here is part of its code:

```
c = ft.Container(
                ft.Text(value="Admin Page", color="cyan", size=50),
                border_radius = 10,
                offset = ft.transform.Offset(0, 0),
                scale=ft.transform.Scale(scale=2),
                animate_offset = ft.animation.Animation(1500, ft.AnimationCurve.FAST_OUT_SLOWIN),
            )
            def animate(e):
                a = 2
                c.offset = ft.transform.Offset(0, -4)
                for i in range(100):
                    c.scale = ft.transform.Scale(a)
                    time.sleep(0.015)
                    c.update()
                    a -= 0.01
                c.update()

            page.add(
                c,
                ft.ElevatedButton("Login", on_click=animate),
            )
```

I need either the button to disappear when clicked, or for the animation to appear when the page loads, and not when the button is clicked. Thanks in advance, sorry for bad English.

I tried adding a transparency value to the animation function so I could return it later, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
import time

# Function to animate the container
def animate():
    a = 2
    c.offset = ft.transform.Offset(0, -4)
    for i in range(100):
        c.scale = ft.transform.Scale(a)
        time.sleep(0.015)
        c.update()
        a -= 0.01
    c.update()

# Function to hide the button when clicked
def hide_button(e):
    page.remove(button)

# Create the container
c = ft.Container(
    ft.Text(value="Admin Page", color="cyan", size=50),
    border_radius=10,
    offset=ft.transform.Offset(0, 0),
    scale=ft.transform.Scale(scale=2),
    animate_offset=ft.animation.Animation(1500, ft.AnimationCurve.FAST_OUT_SLOWIN),
)

# Create the button
button = ft.ElevatedButton("Login", on_click=hide_button)

# Add the container and button to the page
page.add(c, button)

# Trigger the animation when the page loads
animate()
```

**Button Disappearance on Click:** You can simply hide the button when it's clicked.

**Animation on Page Load:** You can trigger the animation as soon as the page loads.

Comment: Thank you. By the way, for the code to work you need to add argument e to the hide_button function